# Updating Android project from command line

Tags: android, command-line, android-studio

I have a project I created in Android Studio. I want to update the package name, packageName inside java files, inside xml files, Android manifest and in build.gradle. I am using this command:

```
android update project --path /pathToMyProject --package updatedPackageName
```

however this command gives an error `Error: Flag '--package' is not valid for 'update project'.`

So the question is how can I achieve my objective using command line so that I can automate the process?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use of `android` tool is deprecated; instead use `sdkmanager`:

```
 androidsdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Comment: thank u bro, seems your answer helped me a lot! But the further question is don't you know the same good replacement for ADB - to get it without downloading the studio?

Comment: Hi kay27, try this:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

There are links for "Download SDK Platform-Tools for <platform>"

Comment: Thanks Peter Tran! Finally got it by `sdkmanager "platform-tools"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Android SDK Command line tools installed:
[image]

and then the path is: `androidsdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager` (default path for on a mac: `~/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager`

Answer (score 0):

The command-line `android` tool hasn't been kept up-to-date for Gradle-based projects like Android Studio uses, so you're better off not using it.

Comment: so anyother ways of achieving what I am trying to do? Or creating multiple copies of the project by changing their package names.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do. If you want to build many versions of a similar application you can investigate using product flavors in the build system. But if you just want to clone the project and change a bunch of things like this, you'd probably have to write your own script to automate it.